# validation on IList property dataannotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

i have scenario like order form where one order can have multiple OrderLines. i am implementing this on single page in asp.net mvc (master detail form) my view Model looks like

public class Order

```
{
   public int OrderID{get;set;}
   public int CustomerID{get;set;}
   public DateTime OrderDate{get;set;}
   public string ShippingAddress{get;set;}
   [ProductUnique(ErrorMessage = "Product must be unique in an order")]
   public IList<OrderLineItem> ProductLines{get;set;}
}

public class OrderLineItem 
{
   public int OrderLineItemID{get;set;}
   public int ProductID{get;set;}
   public int Quantity{get;set;}
}
```

i want ProductUnique attribute to enforce that one product could appear only once in one order my questions are

1. is there some out of the box solution to this problem
2. if i have to roll my    own
   validation attribute how can i
   hook it on client side where should 
   the error message be displayed (with
   property or in validation summary). 
   if i can have it attached with
   property that would be really great

currently we are on mvc2 but we are planning to upgrade so any answer with mvc3 would be equally good. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tangential but I'm thinking validation is not the right approach here.  Why not make your model look like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID{get;set;}
    public int CustomerID{get;set;}
    public DateTime OrderDate{get;set;}
    public string ShippingAddress{get;set;}
    public IDictionary<int, int> ProductQuantities{get;set;}
}
```

Then, if your user adds an existing product to an order, just present the current quantity and offer options for incrementing it.  This way, you're guiding the user into using your interface correctly as opposed to letting them make a mistake and then punishing them with a validation message.